# How to make npm output more readable under Vagrant?

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant, stderr

I have a Vagrantfile which performs some `npm install`s as part of the provisioning process. The most straightforward example command is:

```
sudo npm -g --color=false --loglevel=http install npm@latest
```

... which updates the system's npm version to the latest available. However, the log output of this command, sent to standard error, is very broken up and difficult to read effectively:

```
==> my_vagrant_app: npm
==> my_vagrant_app:
==> my_vagrant_app: http
==> my_vagrant_app:
==> my_vagrant_app: request
==> my_vagrant_app:  GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
==> my_vagrant_app: npm
==> my_vagrant_app:
==> my_vagrant_app: http
==> my_vagrant_app:
==> my_vagrant_app: 304
==> my_vagrant_app:  https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
==> my_vagrant_app: ...
```

I tried adding `--no-spin` and `--no-progress` (wasn't sure which one was applicable to npm v3) but saw no effect.

It looks as though the stream of output is split up based on where an ANSI color sequence or something would be. Is there a hidden switch on npm instead of `--color=false` that can clean up these spurious extra newlines? Barring that, is there a utility I could pipe stderr through to strip them out with?

Comment: What if you just do `sudo npm i -g npm`?

Comment: @migg We'd lose the loglevel for one, which is something we want to have...